# What does setup() do in JS working with PI's GPIO pins

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

Every time you work with the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins with JavaScript / NodeJS, you have to use `x.setup('something')`, with `x` being your imported library or packet. I know your application does not work without it, but what does `setup()` do and what is the parameter you give with it?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: I use Wiring-Pi, but the documentation that I found (http://wiringpi.com/reference/setup/) were not quite clear for me. I downloaded a project (https://github.com/leon-anavi/rpi-nodejs-examples) to see if I could work it out that way but I still don't really get how the `setup()` works.

Comment: docs for `wiring-pi` nodejs module https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Node/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#setupmode

Comment: Aha, thanks. This cleared it up for me. If I copied the stuff from the project given above it would not have worked (I need GPIO, not WPI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Setup documentation (github)](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Node/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#setupmode):

*setup(mode)
.>= 0.1.1
An handy function to setup wiringPi
mode can be one of the following values:*

```
wpi: sets up pin numbering with wiringPiSetup >= 0.1.1
gpio: sets up pin numbering with wiringPiSetupGpio >= 0.1.1
sys: sets up pin numbering with wiringPiSetupSys >= 0.1.1
phys: sets up pin numbering with wiringPiSetupPhys >= 1.0.0
```

*More info about pin numbering systems [here](http://wiringpi.com/pins/)*

*NOTE: >= 2.0.0 no longer accept calling setup without mode specified. (defaulting to wpi in < 2.0.0)*

Given by @Roland Starke.